# Is there a big difference in working with Fedora and Debian servers?

Tags: debian, fedora

Is there a big difference in working with Fedora and Debian servers?

Does either have better community support?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using CentOS instead of Fedora for your server, unless you know you need something that only Fedora offers -- CentOS is the community rebuild of Red Hat Enterprise (more or less, some minor changes) and has a 5-year lifespan and the emphasis is on stability; Fedora, while it can be used for servers, is better suited to a desktop where you want the latest and greatest user apps.

Answer (score 2):

Enough to be annoying, not enough to seriously get in the way of work.  I think Fedora has a greater volume of support, but Debian has higher quality of support.

Comment: so its a quantity over quality thing

Answer (score 0):

Fedora has a very short support life for versions. It is one year I believe, while Debian has a very very long support cycle. Fedora has more current packages, but Debian is considered more stable -- they stick with what is tried and true.

Comment: While a Debian release certainly has a far longer support life than a Fedora release I would hardly call it a "very very long support cycle". As a Debian release is supported until the new release plus an extra year we are on average talking about 3 years support.

Compare that to the 5 years of an Ubuntu LTS server or the 5+ years of a RHEL/CentOS release.

(Not to mention the support cycle Microsoft have offered on 2000 and XP)